# How to roll back delta table to previous version

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

Is there a simple way to choose a previous delta table version as the current/working version?

Instead of creating another version by `overwrite/truncate`, can we just designate a version as the "current/latest" version?

This operation is more like `undo`, which completely remove some steps and make the data to a previous stage. Then when doing `select * from MYTABLE` this `MYTABLE` can point to the restored version.

both SQL or PySpark would be appreicated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find History of delta table by using

```
DESCRIBE HISTORY yourTblName
```

It will give you history of table which includes `Version, TimesStamp, UserId/Name ,Operation`

[image]

To get previous version , you can do few steps, as

```
SELECT max(version) -1 as previousVersion  FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY yourTblName)
```

It will give you previous version(you can save that in some variable) and then use that in **Version As Of**

```
select * from yourTblName Version as of 7
```

You will have records of previous version.

**Restore data table to earlier version:**

```
RESTORE TABLE yourTblName  TO VERSION AS OF 7
```

Databricks Documentation : https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html#restore-a-delta-table-to-an-earlier-state

Comment: How do we drop the later version? eg. I want the versioin 7 only and drop version 8. Then I want be able to ```select * from yourTblName``` to automatically point to version 7

Comment: Read data-bricks documentation on this.https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html#restore-a-delta-table-to-an-earlier-state                   Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the table to a later version and than use vaccum command

Restore can be done using

```
    RESTORE TABLE Table_name TO version of Version_no
```

Vaccum can be done using the vaccum command

```
    Vaccum table Table_name retain 0 hours
```

Retain 0 hours will remove all history snapshots there is a spark config that you need to set before vaccum as by default delta logs are maintained for 7 days.

```
    spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", False)
```

above is the condition to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark way to restore a table to an earlier version.
Works for delta table with unknown name.

1. Load the table

   ```
   from delta.tables import *
   deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/path/to/delta/table/")
   ```
2. Restore to certain version

   ```
   deltaTable.restoreToVersion(5)
   ```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-utility

Comment: can we create a function for same in python.Can anyone share idea to do same using a UDF